# Faster way to plot an image with PIL?

Tags: python, image, plot, drawing

I have a set of (x,y) coordinates rasterized from a sketch:

```
x = [167, 109, 80, 69, 58, 31]
y = [140, 194, 227, 232, 229, 229]
```

I want to recreate that sketch and save it as an image. At the moment I am using PIL draw line function, like this:

```
from PIL import Image, ImageDraw

im = Image.new('L', (256, 256), 255)
draw = ImageDraw.Draw(im)
for i in range(len(x)-1):
    draw.line((x[i],y[i], x[i+1], y[i+1]),fill=0,width=2)
im.save('test.png')
```

[image: output]

I wonder if there is a faster way to do it. The (x,y) points are in drawing order, so maybe using `Image.putdata()` could help?

Comment: `Image.putdata()` would require you to create the pixel data by some other means and then stuff it into an `Image` object—which I doubt you want to do unless you can find some existing module to do it (draw the line). You're doing it the fastest way possible with the PIL.

Comment: Note however that [`ImageDraw.line()`](http://pillow.readthedocs.io/en/4.3.x/reference/ImageDraw.html#PIL.ImageDraw.PIL.ImageDraw.ImageDraw.line) will accept _all_ the coordinates in a single call, so you could remove the `for` loop and gain at least some speed improvement.

Comment: Get rid of the `for` loop and try a using a single `draw.line(*zip(x, y), fill=0, width=2)` call.

Comment: @martineua: awesome. I did't know we can do that. `draw.line(zip(x, y), fill=0, width=2)` works for me (without an asterisk). Not sure if it is faster but at least the code looks very neat now. Please convert your comment into an answer. If no one gives a better solution in the next 2 days I will accept it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This more-or-less demonstrates what I was suggesting in the comments (sans the `*` prefix on the `zip()` call) about being able to draw the entire line using only one call to `draw.line()`.

The advantages are it'll take less code and might be *slightly* faster (even if that's not noticeable with the test data).

```
try:
    from itertools import izip
except ImportError:  # Python 3
    izip = zip
from PIL import Image, ImageDraw

x = [167, 109, 80, 69, 58, 31]
y = [140, 194, 227, 232, 229, 229]

im = Image.new('L', (256, 256), 255)
draw = ImageDraw.Draw(im)

#for i in range(len(x)-1):
#    draw.line((x[i],y[i], x[i+1], y[i+1]), fill=0, width=2)

draw.line(list(izip(x, y)), fill=0, width=2) # Draws entire line.
#im.save('test.png')
im.show()  # Display the image.
```